# List Method returns set

Tags: java

I need some help with creating one small method which will take a list as a parameter and search through another list and if it matches with the parameter we pass then the method will return a set of matching entries.

Any input would be appreciated. I'm new to this forum. If I didn't post in correct category then I'm sorry please guide me to the right place.

getPopularNames(popular);

Here's my code:

```
public List filterNames(List namesList){
    Set namesToExclude = new HashSet();
    List popular = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < namesList.size(); i++){
        NamesList criteria = new (NamesList) namesList.get(i);
        criteria.setPopularExclusionSet(popularExclusionSet);
        popular.add(criteria);
    }
        getPopularNames(popular);
}
```

Comment: just so you know, an "array" is something quite different from a `List`

Comment: @Bohemian -- How so?  Really just different names for the same concept.

Comment: @Hot Licks: An array would be `String[] namesList;`

Comment: An array is an ordered collection (same as a list).  Java has "ArrayList", after all, and several C variants have similar "array" objects.

Comment: what is a "NamesList" object?  Or is that a typo?

Comment: An array's size can't be changed once constructed, unlike a `List`.  The `ArrayList` class is a list which uses an array internally to store its items, but hey I'm not going to war over it.  It's just nomenclature.  We all knew what was meant.

Comment: @HotLicks "Same concept"??? On the contrary, they are **unrelated**, except by the most broad of definitions. They are certainly unrelated from a java perspective. Although all `Collections` ultimately *use* arrays, because an array is the only native way of storing multiple things. Nevertheless they are not interchangeable in the language except for the `foreach` loop, which specifically allows for *either* an array *or* an `Iterable` (but the compiler must deal with then in completely separate ways).

Comment: Whatever you say.  I'm sure whatever your experience is trumps my 40 years in the biz.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I think you want something like this:

```
Set<String> names;
Set<String> popularNames;
...
names.retainAll(popularNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `getPopularNames(popular)` returns a list then you only need to have a `return` statement in your method,

```
return getPopularNames(popular);
```

Comment: is this part: `NamesList criteria = new (NamesList) namesList.get(i);` correct syntax?